# How to add element div before text (How to append text within an element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

Hello I have a element `<a href='#'>whatsapp-300</a>` and i want select before this mark `-` and make it like this `<i class='fa fa-whatsapp'></i>` knowing that the word whatsapp is not fixed and can be facebook and others .. i want a way to do this either by JavaScript or jQuery .. and thank you :D

What I mean is to pick the text before this tag `-` and put it inside its own element

Comment: Get the content then .split("-")[0] and create you're <i> tag using native Javascript is fine, but it can be done in JQuery too :)

Comment: can you help me please how i can make it !!

Comment: If you're looking for a spooned solution, you're not at the right place. Please, show what you've tried so far.

Comment: `<ul class="social-widget social"><li><a href="#">whatsapp-300</a></li></ul>`
this my code html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will look for every single a element and do what you want to it and remove is ext from it as well

```
$('a').each(function(){
        let text=$(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
        let name=text.split("-");
        let logo=document.createElement("i");
        logo.classList += "fa fa-"+name[0];
        $(this).text("");
        $(this).append(logo);
    });
```

Comment: how i can select after this mark `-` and add inside **div** it like this `<div>300</div>` knowing that the number 300 is not fixed and can be 400 and other

Comment: where the div should be?